# How to get eclipse Dynamic Web Project working in elastic beanstalk

Tags: java, eclipse, webserver, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a spring boot java web server running in AWS elastic beanstalk that was created 3 years ago. I am trying to recreate it now using current versions of tomcat, eclipse and the AWS plugin and can't get it to work. I do not want to use spring boot again in this server but will if I have to.

No matter what I try I can't access a servlet in the web project, and all servlet requests result in 404 not found errors. Requests for static HTML pages work properly.

I have searched for answers and found some tips for old versions of tomcat (name your war ROOT.war) and a suggestion that using web.xml instead of modern servlet annotations will help. None of these suggestions solved the problem and I have tried many combinations of different versions of Tomcat and various servlet mapping techniques with no luck.

To ask for help, I have listed the following steps. I am suggesting Tomcat v7 because it uses web.xml as my old server did. I would be happy to use v8.5 if possible, or change any other step, to get this basic Hello World sample running in elastic beanstalk.

Here are the steps:

- create new Dynamic Web Project (TestProject) in eclipse

  - target runtime = Tomcat v7 (which still uses web.xml)
  - web module version = 2.5 (which does not use annotations)
  - accept all other defaults
- added index.html (to prove war is deployed in elastic beanstalk)

  - simple content, containing just a Hello World
- add new servlet (org.example.TestServlet)

  - accept all defaults including generated eclipse code stubs
- test static content in eclipse

  - select project, right click menu, Debug As / Debug on Server
  - can view index.html in browser
- test servlet in eclipse

  - select TestServlet, right click menu, Debug As / Debug on Server
  - can view output: "Served at: /TestProject"
  - url is: http://localhost:8080/TestProject/TestServlet
- export TestProject.war to disk

  - optimize for Tomcat v7
- setup elastic beanstalk

  - create new web server environment
  - select Tomcat Preconfigured platform (this is v8.5)
  - upload TestProject.war
- test static content in elastic beanstalk

  - request in browser: http://my-env.ejppddd6xm.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
  - can view index.html in browser
- test servlet in elastic beanstalk

  - request in http://my-env.ejppddd6xm.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/TestProject/TestServlet
  - get HTTP 404 not found error

No matter what I change, the servlet test always results in a 404 error. I can do the same test on my old server built 3 years ago and it works.

I have also tried an AWS Java Web Project using the AWS plugin, but it results in a corrupt project with a low-level Maven error. I have reported this to AWS.

Can anyone suggest a change in the above steps that will result in successful servlet test within elastic beanstalk?